# use awk to extract row records contain specific word

Tags: shell, awk

Say my input file is tab delimited, how do i identify if $0 contains a word "hello" and it needs to be case insensitive?

```
here is a hello       whateverColumn2
nonono nonono         whateverItIs
here HeLLo again      mockColumn2
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your lines in file `data.txt`:

```
awk -F"\t" '/hello/ {print $0}' data.txt
```

will print

```
here is a hello       whateverColumn2
here hello again      mockColumn2
```

The `-F"\t"` sets tab as the field separator for the input lines.

*Update* (based on request in comments below by OP):

To make this [case-insensitive](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Case_002dsensitivity.html#Case_002dsensitivity) use the `IGNORECASE` flag:

```
awk -F"\t" 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} /hello/ {print $0}' data.txt
```

Note that the [IGNORECASE variable](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gawk/gawk_116.html#IDX863) is a GNU extension and may not be available in other versions of AWK.

Alternatively, an example using `match`. In order to make this case-insensitive, the input is converted into lower case:

```
awk -F"\t" '{if (match(tolower($0), "hello")) print $0}' data.txt
```

Since match can take [regular expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp.html), the conversion to lowercase may not be necessary with the right regular expression.

Tested with GNU Awk 3.1.6 under Linux

Comment: Thanks Levon. What if it needs to be case insensitive? :)

Comment: also, the script isn't as simple as this one since i have lots of other stuff...I wonder how to use the match method to do this?

Comment: @nanshi I answered the ignore case part and also basic matching. If you have a more complex thing you need to do, I would ask a separate question, otherwise I think the focus of this one might be migrating too much :-)

Comment: @nanshi Won't this do what you need to?

Comment: Levon, sorry...what the /hello/ is matching with? with $0, $1, $2 all?

Comment: @nanshi /hello/ is matching the line, so $0

Comment: @nanshi I just added another example for case-insensitve matching using `match`. By the way, do you need line numbers, if not, I'll get rid of that part of the answer.

Comment: Levon, the line contains $0, $1, $2 etc and it's tab delimited (i cannot write tabs in the sample input file here). Do i do ($0 ~ /hello/) ...it doesn't seem to work..thanks

Comment: @nanshi This will work with a tab delimited file. I have shown you two different ways to match, I am not sure I understand your question, why won't the two options given work for you?

Comment: nanshi, it might be recommendable to check the manual of awk to get a better feeling on how regular expressions work. http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp.html

Comment: Levon, thanks for your help. gpoo, thank you too. I think i have a bug somewhere in my script so that the matching stuff doesn't work. I will investigate.

Comment: @nanshi Happy to help .. Once you locate the problem, it might be best to post a new question. Good luck.

Comment: +1, but it should be noted that IGNORECASE is not standard awk but is a gnu extension.  It may be supported in other versions of awk as well.

Comment: @WilliamPursell That's true, I thought the link I posted re case-insensitivity mentioned that (but I can't find it now), and that was also part of the reason why I explicitly stated I tested this with gawk. But you are right, I should make a specific  note about this to improve the answer. Thanks.

Comment: IGNORECASE works for me since the awk version i am using is a gawk. Two methods working. It was not matching due to a bug in my script, i.e. i grabbed a wrong column/field.....thanks a lot, guys! :)

Comment: @nanshi gawk is pretty common, another reason I didn't explicitly state the fact about the IGNORECASE - but WilliamPursell's comment encouraged me to do so. Happy to hear you made progress with your script :)